# Oracle sql order by with character in order

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-order-by

Good day, Maybe someone can help me , i want to get n select output on oracle sql , but when i order by it is not correct.

```
code_order
1.
2.
2.1
3.
4.2
10.1
10.0
21.
21.1
23.
31.
```

it needs to be ordered numeric and all values has a full stop in`.`

any ideas??

Thanx, but i see that some values can contain non numeric values as well like C,B etc.

1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 7C. 40. 50. 51. 6.

Table outline :

code_order is varchar2

Comment: Your types may not be numeric, which is why it is ordering them arbitrarily. You may need a `CAST` somewhere; but without knowing the schema of your table and the query being used, cannot give you a better answer.

Comment: Is `10.0` meant to be after `10.1`?

Comment: Edit the Question and post a better example with all cases, the wrong result and the desired result.

Comment: what means 7C.? in this in hexa? or you want to get rid of C? what do you want to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

use `order by to_number(code_order)`

Comment: `to_number` will error if the field has `characters` on it, which it does (according to OP).

Comment: the caracters came after my response. He did not explain yet what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    with
    val as
    (
      SELECT '1.' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '2.' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '3.' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '2.1' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '4.2' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '10.1' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '21.' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '10.0' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '21.1' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '23.' as c FROM dual
      union all
      SELECT '31.' as c FROM dual
    )
SELECT c FROM val
order by to_number(regexp_replace(c, '^(\d+)\..*$', '\1'))
    ;
```